# How can I create a new Date instance in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime, activesupport

How can I create a new Date object in IRB with a given date.
The following didn't work.

```
1.9.3p194 :053 > require 'active_support'
 => true 
1.9.3p194 :054 > Date.new
 => #<Date:0x9d80730> 
1.9.3p194 :055 > Date.parse('12/01/2012')
NoMethodError: undefined method `parse' for Date:Class
        from (irb):55

1.9.3p194 :055 > Date.new('12/01/2012')
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)
```

Comment: Did you look at the documentation?

Comment: yes i did.  Thank You.  Still looking for answers.

Comment: This http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html says I should be able to use the methods the way I was trying.

Comment: You need to `require 'date'` to get the standard library implementation - the core class is a stripped down version. Yes, it is quite confusing.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

According to [Date documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html):

```
require 'date'

Date.new(2001,2,25)           #=> #<Date: 2001-02-25 
Date.jd(2451966)             #=> #<Date: 2001-02-25 
Date.ordinal(2001,56)        #=> #<Date: 2001-02-25 
Date.commercial(2001,8,7)    #=> #<Date: 2001-02-25 
Date.parse('2001-02-25')     #=> #<Date: 2001-02-25 
Date.strptime('25-02-2001', '%d-%m-%Y') #=> #<Date: 2001-02-25 
Time.new(2001,2,25).to_date   #=> #<Date: 2001-02-25
```

Comment: For those who wonder if the implicit order of the parameters is inspired by  American or the rest of the world date ordering,  the ordering of the parameters is  a logical and neutral ```Date.new(year, month, day)```.

Comment: would be so much easier to guess if simply put as `Date.new(2001, 2, 25)`

Comment: Updated from "02-03" to "02-25" per the suggestion :)

Answer (score 4):

```
1.9.3-p125 :012 > require 'date'
 => true 
1.9.3-p125 :013 > Date::new(2012,02,03)
 => #<Date: 2012-02-03 ((2455961j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
1.9.3-p125 :014 >
```

Answer (score 3):

I find the following easier to remember than `Date.new`:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/string'
'2019-03-31'.to_date
=> #<Date: 2019-03-21 ((2458564j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

See https://apidock.com/rails/String/to_date

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to get active_support extensions to Date outside of Rails, you'll have to use the core_ext module:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/date/calculations'
Date.parse('12/01/2012')
=> #<Date: 2012-01-12 ((2455939j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

More info in this Rails guide: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html

Comment: The standard library Date class supports `parse` too, so no need for ActiveSupport for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Date.strptime("2012-09-21 19:45:48","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the date extension from the Ruby Standard Library.
Most examples in the docs don't always show you to require it.

```
require 'date'
```

was what you needed. It's not a built in set of Classes or Modules.

You get two Classes with that addition,

```
Date
DateTime
```

And with that you may now use info found in the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'date'
Date::strptime("29-05-2017", "%d-%m-%Y")
```

So, you need to include this *date* module in your code and then use the method *strptime* inside which you may notice for year, I have used capital **Y** because full year is entered as the first parameter of the strptime method. You can use small **y** if the date is like '29-05-17'.